# Constructor Chaining without this()

Tags: java, constructor

I understand that constructor chaining goes from the smallest constructor to the biggest. For example

```
    public MyChaining(){
        System.out.println("In default constructor...");
    }
    public MyChaining(int i){
        this();
        System.out.println("In single parameter constructor...");
    }
    public MyChaining(int i,int j){
        this(j);
        System.out.println("In double parameter constructor...");
    }
```

Also as I understand that the call to `this()` and `super()` must be in the first line. But is it possible (and if yes, is it efficient) to bypass that limit and chain constructors different?

For example I have this two constructors that share some code.

```
    public Location(String _Name) throws IOException, JSONException {
        //Three lines of unique code (must be executed before the shared code)
        //Shared code
    }

    public Location(JSONObject json) {
        //Shared code
    }
```

Is it in any way possible for the first constructor to call the second?

Comment: @Philipp yes it is and will be done as so. I was just wondering if it can be done through chaining because I couldn't find an answer elsewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. If you have a `static` function

`JSONObject foo(String)`

then you can write

```
public Location(String _Name) throws IOException, JSONException {
    this(foo(_Name));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to run shared code without calling `this` is that both constructors call some initialization method that would contain the shared code.

```
public Location(String _Name) throws IOException, JSONException {
    //Three lines of unique code (must be executed before the shared code)
    init ();
}

public Location(JSONObject json) {
    init (); // perhaps the JSONObject should be passed to that method, otherwise
             // that parameter is useless. On the other hand, I don't see a
             // JSONObject in the other constructor
}

private void init () {
    // shared code
}
```

Comment: Yes I know it can be done this way. I was wondering if it can be done through chaining and only.

Comment: init() method has another difficulty. You can't initialize final instance fields in that method.

Comment: @Akaitenshi Chaining is only done with `this();` and must be the first line of the constructor.

Comment: @Eran Ok thank you then. The shared code is actually JSON parsing so no final fields in there. The first constructor calls a read method that gets the JSON from a URL. The second an gets the JSON directly from other classes.

Answer (score 1):

A somehow different answer: don't do that.

Constructors are like any other members of your class - they should make sense "altogether". Having constructors that offer completely "different" or "independent" "interfaces" to the user looks like a code smell to me.

You see; if you can "draw" a line through your class; and you find that some elements go ever on the left side, and many others go to the right side of that line; then that is an indication that maybe you should split your class along that "line" and create two classes instead.

If you really want to create the same sort of object from different contexts; then try to identify the "common denominator piece X"; and provide a constructor for exactly that X. And then use factory methods that maybe use that common constructor in different ways. This means that you either provide static methods within the same class, like

```
static Location generateLocationFromFoo(Foo foo) { ... }
static Location generateLocationFromBar(Bar bar) { ... }
```

Or going one step further and create a separate factory class that is used to generate the actual Location objects for you.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't fully understand your last sentence. You mean I can call a constructor from a method inside the same class and use this method to instantiate my Object?

Comment: Updated the answer; hope that helps.

Comment: So I would call the constructor inside `generateLocation` and call `objName.generateLocation()` on my main or when I want the object?

Answer (score 1):

I find the chaining from the smallest constructor to the biggest pattern quite unreadable, since the actual constructor logic is spread over many different methods.

I find it most readable to:

- Have one "main" constructor that fully handles the instance initialization
- Have all the other constructors call it

Also I somewhat dislike long chaining (hard to get to the actual code if drilling down from a simple constructor), so I tend to write all other constructors to directly call the "main" one unless it means duplicate code.

You can always get around the "`this()` must be the first statement" restriction by calling a static method, unless you try to do something that this rule is actually trying to prevent (e. g. use a half-initialized object). **Note that the called function must be static** exactly to prevent you from using the half-initialized object.